# Pandas bar plot is greyed out

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting a `pandas` dataframe, `df.plot(kind='bar',...)`, with lots of bars (+5000), being careful to define the bar width equal to the spacing between my x points. Everything plots fine except for the color of the bars which comes out in light grey, barely visible. Do you have an hint why is this happening? How can I change this color?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(5000)
y = np.random.random(5000)

df = pd.Series(y,x)
example = df.plot(kind="bar", color="red", width=1.)

fig = example.get_figure()
fig.savefig("example.pdf")
```

Comment: You may use key word `color` and set the desire color like `df.plot(kind='bar',color='red',...)`.

Comment: I tried that too, it doesn't work.

Comment: Add your code to question.

Comment: If I run your code, the result is black rather than light grey; this is expected as the borders of the bars are black in the default matplotlib style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see in the plot are not the bars themselves but their edges. So you either need to set the edgecolor to red as well or set the linewidth to zero.

```
df.plot(kind="bar", color="red", edgecolor="red", width=1.)
```

or

```
df.plot(kind="bar", color="red", linewidth=0, width=1.)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought but I didn't know how to remove them.

Comment: I've struggled with this issue for SO long. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the bars, you can just specify the 'color' parameter. For example, to make the bars red, this should work:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', color='r')
```